# PHP: call function on a certain page only

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I am making CRUD application in PHP & mySQLi and i run into this problem: I have a *functions.php file* where, naturally, all my function are stored. This file is included in my *init.php file*.

One of these functions uses a variable available only in the template view_user.php (view_user.php?id=5), like so:

```
function single_user() {
  ...
  $user_id = $_GET['id'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$user_id;
  ...
}
```

Of coarse, am all the other pages, this results into an error: *Undefined index: id...*

How can I make sure this function is called *only when "id" is available*? In other words: only on view_user.php?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `$_GET['id']` is set:

```
function single_user() {
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        ...
        $user_id = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$user_id;
        ...
    }
}
```

so that if it's not you won't attempt to use it and get the undefined index error.